# Conda Kernel in Jupyter with Dockerfile

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, dockerfile, conda

I'd like to have a conda kernel available for my notebooks in JupyterLab and followed the [Conda Environments with Docker](https://medium.com/@chadlagore/conda-environments-with-docker-82cdc9d25754) manual.
My dockerfile so far:

```
FROM jupyter/minimal-notebook
COPY environment.yaml /tmp/environment.yaml

RUN conda env create -f /tmp/environment.yaml
RUN conda init
RUN echo "source activate condaenv" > ~/.bashrc
RUN python -m ipykernel install --user --name=condaenv
```

environment.yaml:

```
name: condaenv
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - ipython
  - ipykernel
  - numpy=1.23.5
```

But this does not show the kernel unless, again executing:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=condaenv
```

in the Terminal of JupyterLab.

What is the way to setup a conda environment within a containerfile?

[nb_conda_kernels](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda_kernels) did not work neither.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Docker Stacks jupyter-* images](https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) already have Conda (and Mamba) initialized. After creation, a new environment simply needs to be registered, which is better done with `conda run`. Adding the new environment to be automatically activated is likely causing problems.

There are also some additional better practices I'd recommend, especially if this is intended for production:

- use Mamba, rather than Conda (faster, better conflict reporting)
- avoid multiple RUN steps (generates unneeded intermediate images)
- discard the Conda package cache
- decouple reliance on the `name:` key in the YAML, instead define this as an argument to the Dockerfile

I'd do something like:

```dockerfile
FROM jupyter/minimal-notebook
COPY environment.yaml /tmp/environment.yaml
ARG env_name=condaenv

RUN mamba env create -f /tmp/environment.yaml -n $env_name && \
    mamba clean -qafy && \
    mamba run -n $env_name python -m ipykernel install --user --name=$env_name
```

And you can drop `ipython` as a requirement in the YAML - having `ipykernel` is sufficient.